# How to access Node.JS project locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

I have a node.js project running on the ubuntu server.---> App is listening on 5000.

So, I want to access it locally. Like http://server_ip:5000

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by access it locally. If have the code you can run locally in you computer and access it by `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: I don't want to run it locally. The app should be running on the server.I want to access it by server ip address.

Comment: in the ubuntu server use command `dig` to get the IP of the server

Comment: I know the ip of server. but can't access by http://server_ip:5000

Comment: Can you access it inside the server, try using curl? If you can, then the port 5000 might not be open to everyone.

Comment: Yah, I did curl localhost:5000. 
I can access it inside the server. So,How can I open the port for everyone?

Comment: Where is your Ubuntu server hosted in AWS?

Comment: On digital ocean.

Comment: Check this out
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/opening-ports-on-my-server

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work for me. Can we have a personal discussion? I'm in trouble.

Comment: Try this, this can help you. If that doesn't help you we can go for a personal discussion...
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know the IP of your server. You can do it by using an `ifconfig` (look for interfaces like `ethX`, `enpXsY`, `enoX` where X and Y are numbers) or `curl icanhazip.com` command. I would recommend to execute both of them and see if the IPs in the output match. If they don't - your server might be located behind NAT and you won't be able to access it unless you forward ports on your NAT host which is outside of the scope of this question.

Another thing you need to keep in mind is that servers can be protected by firewalls. The procedure of adding port 5000 to the allowlist varies for every firewall. `sudo ufw allow 5000` can often do the trick on Ubuntu (but, once again, it may or may not work - for you this procedure can be different).

After this you should be able to access your server by typing `http://<YOUR_SERVER_IP>:5000` in your browser address bar

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the IP of your computer (IPv4). Here's a link to a webpage that shows it to you https://www.whatismyip.com. After this you can simply type in your IP and then add `:<port>`, so in your case `:5000`

Answer (score 0):

For access from the same machine use http://localhost:5000 or use hostname e.g http://hostname:5000. Get hostname by writing **hostname** command from the terminal.

For access from other machines such as your mobile device or laptop, they all need to be connected to the same network, lets say all connected to the same WiFi network. In this case use the IP address of the machine that is running your server.
Lets say if your IP is 192.168.1.1 then for
e.g write  this http://192.168.1.1:5000

Use **ifconfig** for getting IP address.